# Google Analytics - In Page Analytics - Can not see everyone's date only logged in data

Tags: java, javascript, google-analytics

The team @ CliqFlip has built a social network and the problem is that in Google Analytics In Page analytics it only shows the data of you when you're logged in.

I.E. Cannot get to landing page without being logged in, so you're logged in as a user and In Page Analytics only shows your stats where **you** click

What we want: To be able to see where the masses are clicking

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how logging in relates to this problem, but if you want to see where masses are clicking, you should use heatmap solution like [crazy egg](http://www.crazyegg.com/), or implement [event tracking](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerGuide.html) in google analytics.

Going to [your site](http://cliqflip.com/) i can see that tracking beacon is sent correctly.

on your [beta page](http://cliqflip-beta.apphb.com/) tracking is also set up so i'm not sure what's the true problem here

Comment: Well because you have to be logged in to view the landing page - So if you're looking at it through Google Analytics you're logged in through your profile and it only shows your clicks.